# Draw two google line charts from one data table

Tags: google-visualization

I collect data from my arduino sensors into a mysql table then use google graphs to draw line charts with the data. My data is temperature, humidity and a calculated humidex. Part of my project was to draw a guage with the current values which i was able to do. So I select the data into a data table, then filter them using a data view. Then draw three separate guages for each of the filtered values. The problem is temperatures usually go from -40 to 40 let's say and humidity from 0 to 100%, so drawing them in the same graph makes the graph looks flat as far as the temperatures are concerned.

My goal is to draw two graphs without having to query the database twice (if possible of course)

Below is the relevant code

```
echo "[new Date(" . $row["Year"] .", " .$row["Month"].", " .$row["Day"].", " .$row["Hour"].", " .$row["Min"]."), ". $temperature . ", " . $humidex . ", " . $humidity . "]";

var temp_view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      temp_view.setRows([0,1,2]);

var humid_view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      humid_view.setRows([0,3]);

var options = {'title':'Temperature', 'width':650, 'height':500};

var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('temp_chart'));
      chart1.draw(temp_view, options);

var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('humid_chart'));
      chart2.draw(humid_view, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the data results in an array similar to the following...

```
[new Date(2018, 5, 29, 7, 26), 70, 75, 0.98]
```

then you only have one row with 4 columns

which means you should be using `setColumns`, instead of `setRows`...

try...

```
var temp_view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
temp_view.setColumns([0,1,2]);

var humid_view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
humid_view.setColumns([0,3]);

var options = {'title':'Temperature', 'width':650, 'height':500};

var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('temp_chart'));
chart1.draw(temp_view, options);

var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('humid_chart'));
chart2.draw(humid_view, options);
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed that issue. Now I have another problem. This part of the graph is placed inside a <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-5"></div></div> tags along with the javascript. I would like to have the second graph on a different row. Is there a way to do that? I am not sure if multiple pieces of code in javascript can work together if they are scattered between php blocks. Basically what I need to do is put the var chart2 line above in its own row div. Is this possible?